# Hibernate roles and privileges

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to implement roles and privileges. But I get a session error message:

**Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.testmany.shop.entity.AuthoritiesEntity.privilegesEntities, could not initialize proxy - no Session**

Please tell me what am I doing wrong? I have not found a solution on the Internet. I cannot solve this problem for two days.

https://github.com/MyTestPerson/TestMany

**This is how I create a user..**

```
    PrivilegesEntity privilegesEntity = serviceJpa.findPrivilegesEntityByPrivilegeEnum("PRIVILEGE_EDIT");
    AuthoritiesEntity authoritiesEntity = serviceJpa.findAuthoritiesEntityByRoleEnum("ROLE_USER");

    privilegesEntity.addAuthority(authoritiesEntity);
    authoritiesEntity.addUser(userEntity);

    serviceJpa.savePrivilegesEntity(privilegesEntity);
```

[image]

**UserEntity.class**

```
    @Entity(name = "UserEntity")
    @Table(name = "users", schema = "test")
    public class UserEntity implements Serializable {



        private Long id;
        private String email;
        private String password;
        private Collection<AuthoritiesEntity> authoritiesEntities = new ArrayList<>();




        // id
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }




        // email
        @NaturalId
        @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 45)
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }




        // password
        @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 65)
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }





        @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
        public Collection<AuthoritiesEntity> getAuthoritiesEntities() {
            return authoritiesEntities;
        }

        public void setAuthoritiesEntities(Collection<AuthoritiesEntity> authoritiesEntities) {
            this.authoritiesEntities = authoritiesEntities;
        }



    }
```

**AuthoritiesEntity.class**

```
    @Entity(name = "AuthoritiesEntity")
    @Table(name = "authorities", schema = "testmany")
    public class AuthoritiesEntity implements Serializable{

        private Long id;
        private String authority;
        private Collection<UserEntity> userEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
        private Collection<PrivilegesEntity> privilegesEntities = new ArrayList<>();




        // id
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }





        // role
        @Column(name = "authority", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 45, insertable = false, updatable = false)
        public String getAuthority() {
            return authority;
        }

        public void setAuthority(String authority) {
            this.authority = authority;
        }





        

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authoritiesEntities", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        public Collection<UserEntity> getUserEntityList() {
            return userEntityList;
        }

        public void setUserEntityList(Collection<UserEntity> userEntityList) {
            this.userEntityList = userEntityList;
        }





        @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
        public Collection<PrivilegesEntity> getPrivilegesEntities() {
            return privilegesEntities;
        }

        public void setPrivilegesEntities(Collection<PrivilegesEntity> privilegesEntities) {
            this.privilegesEntities = privilegesEntities;
        }






        // addUser
        public void addUser(UserEntity userEntity) {
            userEntityList.add( userEntity );
            userEntity.getAuthoritiesEntities().add( this );
        }





    }
```

**PrivilegesEntity.class**

```
    package com.testmany.shop.entity;

    import com.testmany.shop.enam.PrivilegeEnum;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;

    @Entity(name = "PrivilegesEntity")
    @Table(name = "privileges", schema = "testmany")
    public class PrivilegesEntity implements Serializable {



        private Long id;
        private String privilege;
        private Collection<AuthoritiesEntity> authoritiesEntityList = new ArrayList<>();




        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }








        @Column(name = "privilege", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 45, insertable = false, updatable = false)
        public String getPrivilege() {
            return privilege;
        }

        public void setPrivilege(String privilege) {
            this.privilege = privilege;
        }








        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privilegesEntities", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        public Collection<AuthoritiesEntity> getAuthoritiesEntityList() {
            return authoritiesEntityList;
        }

        public void setAuthoritiesEntityList(Collection<AuthoritiesEntity> authoritiesEntityList) {
            this.authoritiesEntityList = authoritiesEntityList;
        }









        // addAuthority
        public void addAuthority(AuthoritiesEntity authoritiesEntity) {
            authoritiesEntityList.add( authoritiesEntity );
            authoritiesEntity.getPrivilegesEntities().add( this );
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search for questions about `LazyInitializationException` you will find a ton of questions with answers that explain why you get that exception and how you can resolve this. In short, the entity manager to which the lazy collection proxy for `privilegesEntities` is connected is not available anymore. The easiest solution and in your case also probably the most appropriate one is to let the transaction (to which the EntityManager is bound) span over the whole method, by annotating the method with `@Transactional`

Comment: I've tried a lot of options but still haven't found a solution.